# UITableViewCell not resizing for UIView subview

Tags: ios, uitableview, resize, autolayout, kstokenview

I added this library called `KSTokenView` which is a tokenizer like `NSTokenField`. This `UIView subclass` was added to the `UITableViewCell`. Connections were made with all the 4 sides of this `UIView` to the content view. Now as I type into the view and the size changes, there is a delegate method for change of frame.

Using the frame change for that, I need to resize my tableviewcell and in turn the tableview also.

In the view controller for the table view, I am giving an `estimated row height` of `UITableViewAutomaticDimension`. I am currently doing `tableView.beginUpdates` and `tableView.endUpdates` on change of frame.

What is the correct way?

Answer (score 0):

I think changing the frame is not the right way to do it (if you're using autolayout). You can set a height constraint to your view and update its constant instead, in the same place you update the frame.

**Update**

> I am giving an estimated row height of UITableViewAutomaticDimension

You shouldn't set `estimatedRowHeight` to be `UITableViewAutomaticDimension`. It should be an estimated average number of your cell height and `rowHeight` should be `UITableViewAutomaticDimension`.

Comment: Okay. I made that change. Thanks.

Comment: Should the height constraint be given for the subview?

Comment: yes. as long as the subview is pinned to the cell from top and bottom.

Comment: I am testing it out. I will mark the answer accordingly as the question sees fit.

Comment: take your time. please let me know if it didn't work.